# align CSS elements in relation to underlying element

Tags: css, html

This is my HTML:

```
<nav id="menu">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="">Produkte</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Angebote</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Referenzen</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anfahrt</a></li>
      <li><a href="">&Uuml;ber uns</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Jobs</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Partner</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Kontakt</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
#menu {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:35px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-image: url("../img/menuBackground.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#menu ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    top:5px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

#menu ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 16px;
}
```

As you might see there is a white stripe in the "menuBackground.png". (So the white stripe is part of the "menuBackground.png" image.) The problem is, that the menu gets generated automatically by a CMS. **And the text in the A elements should never ever overlap the underlying white stripe,** as it is happening with the Kontakt Element.

**How can i ensure, that there will be some additional spacing, when the element overlaps the white stripe?**

Thanks in advance for any reply on this

[image: Screenshot browser]

[image: Original Image]

HERE IS A [JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NwPKk/) ...

Comment: Where does the white stripe come from? Is that part of the background image? I think I see a couple of ways, but if you post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (with a working link to the background-image), I can test them out before posting speculation.

Comment: yes it is part of the background image

Comment: added the JS FIDDLE example - the site uses already uses jquery

Comment: You can't do tha i suppose....But, what you can do is increase the left margin 1px or 2px.....This can't be done for dynamic menus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works:

```
#menu {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#menu ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    top:5px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    background-color: #ff9025;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 8px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #ffbf00;
}

#menu ul li:last-child {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSJSV.png);
    background-position: 63% top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 60px;
}
```

Albeit, it's a bit of a kludge.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kMJWB/).

Effectively I've removed the `background-image` from the `ul` (or the `nav`, I'm not sure, now) and added it to the end of the `li:last-child`<sup>1</sup>, positioning it so that the stripe is seen. This involved adding sufficient padding to that element, and styling the `ul` with the `background-color` of the right side of the image, and the `li` elements with the left side colour in order to feign the image. It's not ideal, but I think it works reliably. Certainly I'd suggest adding, and commenting-out, further `li` elements to test it, though.

**Edited** following my discovery of IE's near complete lack of `:last-child` support, to use jQuery (as you say your site uses it already, in your comments):

```
$('#menu li:last').addClass('lastChild');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kMJWB/1/).

---

**Edited** to what I *think* should be the final version, featuring a feature-detection to enable the jQuery option in the absence of `:last-child` support (albeit I can't explicitly test, as yet, that `:last-child` *itself* doesn't exist, but I suspect that a browser that doesn't support `document.querySelectorAll()` *probably* doesn't support `:last-child`, which is, really, a terrible assumption):

```
if (!document.querySelectorAll){
    $('#menu li:last').addClass('lastChild');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kMJWB/5/).

---

1. This is a problem for older browsers, particularly of the IE vintage, since as I recall versions earlier to 7 had problems with the `:last-child` pseudo-selector. On review of the [compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t35), at [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/), it appears even worse than I thought: no versions lower than IE9 support the `:last-child` selector.

Comment: what a great idea! you're awesome, that's all what i wanted! :-)

Comment: Yeah, I messed up with that. I should've posted an `else if`...sigh. Done that now, and updated the link to the test-case; could you take another look for me?

Comment: your last test-case (kMJWB/3/) doesn't work, but this does: http://jsfiddle.net/KYPkC/2/

Comment: IE8 tells me on your test-case 3: the object doesn't support this property or method querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to add space based on a background-image, it's your responsibility to make it fit exactly how you want (do the math), you could make a div that splits your navigation bar, but for that you have to cut your background image too, 1 for nav part and other for the white stripe, or just lower margins and font size

Comment: the problem is, that we got the design as PSD and integrated it into our existing Typo3 CMS and the menu changes depending on the site you are calling. this makes it a bit of a pain to do it by hand...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Paradise/4ggJL/ check that, that's how you could do it, the above solutions adds padding which is a problem in IE older browsers but thats what I mean when I told you to splut it and cut your background image